# WiX Toolset: Creating a simple WiX project breaks in VS2017: The "CreateProjectReferenceDefineConstants" task was not found

Tags: visual-studio-2017, wix, wix3

I'm new to using Wix, and tried to make a simple installation for my App. I did the following:

1. Downloaded and installed the [Extension for Visual Studio 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vsgallery/2eb3402e-ea6d-4dcd-8340-c88435e54ea9) from [here](http://wixtoolset.org/releases/).
2. Download and installed [WiX Toolset v3.11.1](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/releases/tag/wix3111rtm)
3. Created a Setup Project for WiX v3
4. Added a reference to my App in the project, and added the block in `Product.wxs`:

```html
<Component Id="ProductComponent">
  <File Source="$(var.MyApplication.TargetPath)" />
</Component>
```

When I compile the Wix setup project, I get the following error:

> The "CreateProjectReferenceDefineConstants" task was not found. Check
>   the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the
>   same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and
>   implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task
>   is correctly declared with  in the project file, or in the
>   *.tasks files located in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin" directory.

Any ideas what went wrong? I can't find any mention of this error online. Whatis a task and what is a task class? I was expecting that doing [this quick guide](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/authoring_first_votive_project.html) would be enough for a simple installer.

Comment: Not 100% sure, maybe try to follow the [step-by-step description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47972615/129130) for compiling an MSI using WiX (maybe the inline comments at the bottom code section are fastest). Just replace the absolute path with your variable. I think the key is that those variables are only available once you have a reference set to something WiX - such as the GUI dll. Try it out?

Comment: I just followed the Minimal WiX MSI Compile - Step-By-Step from the link, but the error is still there, I feel like something went wrong with the installation of the extension or the toolset, not sure :/ I wonder if the toolset version has to be a different one? PS. The error is still the same, except this time it says: The "ResolveWixReferences" task... <<the rest of the error text is the same>>

Comment: Yeah, I didn't read that thoroughly. Thought I'd just see if a hint could work. Maybe you have an MSBuild problem? Do you have another machine to test on? (just checking). And the obvious restart of the tool and reboot maybe? Will have a quick look later.

Comment: [Maybe check this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35132076/129130). Build dependency on DotNET 3.5?

Comment: I don't like using project references like that for about a dozen reasons.  If you are new to WiX and creating a simple installer I suggest starting with https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials

Comment: I've installed .NET 3.5 and it fixed the issue. It was strange that WiX Toolset v3.11.1 didn't require that i had this version when I installed the Toolset, but never-mind. Thanks for your help

Comment: David, I have added an answer so you can accept and close. People tend to not read comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***.NET Framework 3.5***: After some debugging the solution was to install the **.NET Framework 3.5**.
>
> - **WiX 3.x** has a build-dependency requiring this version.
> - **WiX 4.x** requires **.NET Core** and **Framework 4+**.

***Procedure***:

1. Hold <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> and **Tap** <kbd>R</kbd>. Type: **`appwiz.cpl`** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Left pane, click "***Turn Windows Features On / Off***".
3. Tick / enable: "***.NET Framework 3.5***".
4. **Run Windows Update (!)** . If you can. To check for security updates.

   - On Windows 10:

     - Hold <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> and **Tap** <kbd>R</kbd>.
     - Type: **`ms-settings:windowsupdate`** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
     - Click "Check for updates".

Now you should be able to build your WiX projects.

Or talk to tech support if you are in a managed environment. They should have a ready-made package for this .NET runtime, unless the runtime itself is prohibited from use.

---

***Links***:

- [Cannot build WIX project on windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35132076/cannot-build-wix-project-on-windows-10/35195270#35195270)
- [Hello WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47972615/129130) - minimal step-by-step example for writing a WiX installer in Visual Studio.
- **Chris Painter's** samples: https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials
- [WiX Quick Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864). Further links to more samples.