# Error The "ResolveWixReferences" task could not be loaded from the assembly

Tags: wix

WiX Toolset v3.11.1

WiX Toolset Visual Studio 2015 Extension

Try Integrating WiX Projects Into Daily Builds as following article.
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/daily_builds.html

WixSetup64bit.wixproj at
C:\Work\TC\WixSetup64bit\

wix311-binaries.zip is extracted to
C:\Work\TC\wix\v3.11\

How to fix following error?

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error The "ResolveWixReferences" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Work\TC\wix\v3.11..\wix\v3.11\wixtasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Work\TC\wix\wix\v3.11\wixtasks.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. WixSetup64bit C:\Work\TC\wix\v3.11\wix2010.targets 735

rebuild again, the error changes to
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error The "ResolveWixReferences" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly declared with in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin" directory. WixSetup64bit C:\Work\TC\wix\v3.11\wix2010.targets 735

Here is the WixSetup64bit.wixproj
[WixSetup64bit.wixproj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfOsr.jpg)

Comment: Did you have any luck? Curious if this is another problem than I expected.

Answer (score 3):

https://programcsharp.com/blog/post/building-wix-with-msbuild

This article solved my problem.

`WixToolPath` needs to be an absolute path for the `Wix.targets` project to function properly, and `WixExtDir` needs to be set to `WixToolPath`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

***Previous Answer:*** Not sure, and it is not a 100% match, but maybe check this answer: [WiX Toolset: Creating a simple WiX project breaks in VS2017: The "CreateProjectReferenceDefineConstants" task was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54913177/wix-toolset-creating-a-simple-wix-project-breaks-in-vs2017-the-createprojectr)

> ***In Essence:*** Is the **.NET framework 3.5** installed on your build computer?
>
> 1. If not, please try to add it: <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + Tap <kbd>R</kbd> => **`appwiz.cpl`** => <kbd>Enter</kbd> => `Turn Windows features on or off`. Tick the `".NET Framework 3.5"` entry and install.
>
>    - **Important**: now **`run Windows Update`** to check for security updates.
> 2. Or - obviously - get the correct deployment package installed from your distribution guys, if you are in a managed environment with standardized software.

Comment: It seems related issues are bitness (32-bit paths, 64-bit paths) and erroneous paths to older WiX versions or similar. [Check here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/549629af-1bb9-4fa9-a94d-de2b4d54b5a3/wix-project-not-working-with-team-build?forum=tfsbuild). Not extensively researched, but if you have the problem it is a start.