# Wix Installer won't build on buildserver

Tags: msbuild, wix, installation, wix3.8, build-server

I have tried to build a Wix MSI using our build server. I have set the build configuration in the Configuration manager to DEBUG/x86. All the other projects build correctly EXCEPT for the Wix Installer.

Initially there was an error requesting the latest version of WIX was installed on the build server "The WiX Toolset v3.11 (or newer) build tools must be installed to build this project. To download the WiX Toolset, see http://wixtoolset.org/releases/" so I follwed this - 
https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web_development/9781784393212/1/ch01lvl1sec12/compiling-a-wix-installer-on-a-build-machine-using-msbuild
also have used this - 
https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/wix_with_team_build.html

Now the build freezes on the Wix project and eventually times oout at 59 minutes. What would be wrong? what needs correctling?

I have tried these suggestions already - https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web_development/9781784393212/1/ch01lvl1sec12/compiling-a-wix-installer-on-a-build-machine-using-msbuild
also have used this - 
https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/wix_with_team_build.html

Expecting it to build, then I can create an MSI file.

Comment: No one on earth can help you since you didn't provide clear repeatable steps. Without steps and a build log showing your results, it is hopeless.

Answer (score 0):

***.NET 3.5***: This might very well be something else, but maybe try to install the **`.NET Framework 3.5`**. **WiX 3.x** has a build-dependency requiring this .NET version.

***How-To***: Please see this answer for more details: [WiX Toolset: Creating a simple WiX project breaks in VS2017: The "CreateProjectReferenceDefineConstants" task was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54913177/wix-toolset-creating-a-simple-wix-project-breaks-in-vs2017-the-createprojectr/54931394#54931394)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I have tried this with no success