# The WiX Toolset v3.11 (or newer) build tools must be installed - Even after installation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wix

I'm trying to restore dependencies in a VS solution via dotnet restore command for a ASP/NET Core app
that uses wix installer tools

The problem is, that even after installing wix build tool 3.11 and wix toolset for VS 2019 and after rebooting the PC I still get an error message - The WiX Toolset v3.11 (or newer) build tools must be installed to build this project

Any idea why it doesnt work?

Comment: Not sure, [check this before trying anything else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56705457/129130).

Comment: Yes, probably you turn off windows features .net freamework 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I found that I was running v3.9x.  I found an 'Unofficial fork' by Rob Mensching and Bob Arnson v3.11.2 which worked.  Remember to close and re-open VS.