# Wixtoolset version says I need a newer version installed (3.11) but it already is installed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, wix3.11

I have a C# project that uses the wixtoolset to create the msi installer.

When I try to run `dotnet build -c Release` I get the follwing error:

`Runtime.Installer.wixproj(43,5): error : The WiX Toolset v3.11 (or newer) build tools must be installed to build this project. To download the WiX Toolset, see http://wixtoolset.org/releases/ 0 Warning(s) 1 Error(s)`

- Visual Studio 2022
- Wix Version 3.11.2.4516

I've uninstalled and reinstalled Wix and the VS Extension multiple times, including multiple system restarts.

Comment: Did you see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62677771/the-wix-toolset-v3-11-or-newer-build-tools-must-be-installed-even-after-inst

Comment: Had not seen that question. .Net Framework 3.5 was turned on for my machine. I turned it off, restarted, same error. Then I renabled it, restarted, still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Found the following

> WiX v3.x does not support building under dotnet build. It is expected to be supported in WiX v4.0; thus the v4.0 milestone.

In this discussion https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5627
However couldn't find any official documentation on the above.
Switched complier to msbuild and managed to get build working.