# Is "could not be loaded" an error fixed by restarting?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, xamarin, xamarin.ios

This is the error.

> The "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.FixedCreateCSharpManifestResourceName"
>   task could not be loaded from the assembly
>   \packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.1.0.6526\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10\Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll.
>   Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly
>   and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a
>   public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Project

I've tried restarting VS, rebuilding the solution, rebuilding each project in the solution, and I tried the solution from the following:

[BuildTasks.Csc task could not be loaded from the assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32150204/buildtasks-csc-task-could-not-be-loaded-from-the-assembly)

However doing that just leads me to the following error:

> Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\Project.dll" to
>   "bin\Debug\Project.dll". The process cannot access the
>   file 'bin\Debug\Project.dll' because it is being used by
>   another process.

I looked into this one and it seems to be "solved" by restarting VS a lot. I was also getting this error before deleting the packages folder, but after restarting I was getting the "task could not be loaded" error.

Comment: check permissions on the folder.  I ran into this same issue and that's what wound up solving the problem for me.  I had moved my projects to an App Drive and you need to put your security on Explicitly even if you are an admin on the PC.

Comment: If your using source control, make sure you have the solution checked out

Comment: @Bearcat9425 It looks like I have Full control on the folders.

Comment: @InitLipton Yes I have the solution checked out.

Comment: @Bearcat9425 okay so I think I solved it. On one of the cleans I noticed that it said it couldn't delete \Project\bin\Debug\Project.dll because access denied. So I deleted the file and cleaned and built the project again. It works now. The \bin\Debug folder now has a bunch of files in it where before it only had the one file.

Answer (score 7):

in solution explorer

right click on References -> Manage Nuget packages...

then

search: xamarin.forms

Author(s): xamarin Inc.

install or uninstall  xamarin.forms package and restart VS

Comment: actually it does not help.

Comment: Follow the instruction and remove the xamarin.form from Android project fixes the problem